# How to take data from a pytest function(monekypath)

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have developed a program that contains many functions. I am now testings these functions. To do this, I have needed to use a monkeypath approach because the function tested calls input.

Because to test the functions I need to get the data of the previous tests, with the monkeypath function I have found difficulties.

```
data_to_test_1 = test_load_sample() # I take the data from the previous test here

# SECOND TEST
def test_take_sample(monkeypatch):
    '''
    take_sample() requests the name of the column
    and take that input to split the data in new columns
    This can be tested by checking some ofthe first values of that
    columns (GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL)
    monkeypatch simulate the input of the user
    '''
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: "373978487") # The 9th sample in the file
    data_to_test_2 = take_sample(data_to_test_1,NAME_FILE_1)
    return data_to_test_2
    assert data_to_test_2["GT"] == "0/1"     # What I test
    assert data_to_test_2["AD"] == "28,46"
    assert data_to_test_2["DP"] == "74:99"


# Now, I want the output of the test_take_sample()
data_to_test_3 = test_take_sample() 

def test_filter_1():
   ... # this function will use data_to_test_3
```

I have followed the same approach with previous functions to concatenated the data from one test to the following one but with this that involves the monkeypath thing I got

```
test_take_sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'monkeypatch'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue with this

```
data_to_test_2,Name_sample = take_sample(data_to_test_1,NAME_FILE_1)
```

I have jumped the test test_take_sample() and I have just run the function take_sample. This has asked me the input and I have introduce the input adding   `-s` when the test has been run like this: `pythest test_1.py -s`

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, I think function test_load_sample() did not need parameter. So you allocate 'data_to_test_1' about the value of the function 'test_load_sample()'

if you make
data_to_test_1 = test_load_sample()
data_to_test_1 receive return value of test_load_sample() not function itself

I think you think that you are allocating function to data_to_test_1 but it is not. you just allocate value of the function.

If you wanna allocate function to some variable, Use 'class' type

Comment: Yes, you are right. data_to_test_1 receive return value. In every step, I need the value of the previous test. In previous tests it worked but now in a test in which I am using the moneypath I do not know what is wrong

Comment: In data_to_test_3 I need the return of test_take_sample()

Comment: And I dont want to allocate function to some variable

Comment: Hmm... I cannot fully understand your problem. I thought you wrote the code because you wanna use class type but you only need value of function. If you see the error code, "test_take_sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'monkeypatch'" means that you need to insert parameter 'monkeypatch' to test_take_sample. Isn't it the problem? like;
hahapatch = 'asdfasdf';
data_to_test_1 = test_load_sample(hahapatch);